# Slack API Bolt-JS is not differentiating `app.message`'s

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api, bolt

In this minimal example :

```
app.message(/Foo/i, async ({ message,say }) => {
  await say("Bar!")
})
app.message(/Snoo/i, async ({ message,say }) => {
  await say("Reddit!")
})
```

Then oddly enough if I write in Slack :

```
Snoo
=> Reddit!
Foo
=> Bar!
   Reddit!
```

It appears that the second `app.message` automatically runs regardless if its message is called. Perhaps the namespace of `say` is usurped by the former?

How can I isolate them?

Comment: Question... I'm on the Java SDK  and just posted this - @Trip - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73827813/slack-bolt-java-sdk-multiple-app-message-events-with-different-regex-stomp-on.  It seems like multiple app.message() blocks stomp on each other (like totally replace each other).  Did you ever get this working or find out more?

Comment: No I didn't actually @JohnHumphreys. But in my case, they all appear.

Comment: I gave up and made a .* handler and continued to route messages myself inside it with my own patterns from a yaml file.  The app.message thing seems very odd :).  But oh well.